# Apache Superset Add Database button missing

Tags: apache-superset

I have installed apache superset on CentOS.
I am unable to see the add database button.
I have a staging superset where the add database button is visible and everything is working fine. I am moving this to a prod server and installed superset there and the add database button is missing.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

It should appear as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with sqlalchemy package.

The version installed was 1.4.42 and the button was not appearing on the UI.
So I uninstalled it and installed version 1.3.24. This resolved the issue.

I compared the pip list for my working staging superset and prod superset.
The difference was in the sqlalchemy package version.

Dumb!